# Requesting a Cookie Returns Null in ASP.NET Web API

Tags: javascript, angular, asp.net-web-api

I have created a cookie in an angular application but using ngx-cookie-service and set the cookie to

```
this.cookie.set('UserNameToAccessFromWebAPI', data.UserName)
```

I can see the cookie in browser's application section but the problem is when I request it in asp.net web API I only get null value

```
[HttpGet]
        public IHttpActionResult GetEntries()
        {
            try
            {
                using (AppDbContext context = new AppDbContext())
                {
        --->        var cookie = Request.Headers.GetCookies("UserNameToAccessFromWebAPI").FirstOrDefault(); ;

        --->        string test = cookie["UserNameToAccessFromWebAPI"].Value;

                    IEnumerable<Entry> entries = (from b in context.Entries join p in context.Users on b.User equals p.UserName where p.IsLoggedIn == true select b).ToList();

                    return Ok(entries);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return BadRequest(e.Message);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you're making the get/post request to your backend make sure to include the withCredentials flag. You can see it here: https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpRequest